# Unable to run Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise update for December 2020

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Currently I have two servers with Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise that I have to update manually each month for Microsoft's patches.  This has worked fine since requesting it not be blocked by McAfee since Winter 2019-2020.

However, back in December 2020, I ran the updates and they said they were fine.  They had the version of 15.9.29 in early December (before 12/8/2020 patch).

After the new patch came out on the 8th of December, I tried running the updates for VS and found that VS told me it was up to date and did not pull down any updates.  I know that is wrong because 15.9.30 came out back on 12/8/2020.  The only message I get is I'm up to date and the system goes on.

I tried running the updates from both the application and the installer, neither of which noted a new update.

One thought I had on this issue is our team was being blocked again by McAfee, but there is no new block for it.  VS just doesn't seem to want to pull down the update.

Are there any tricks (short of reinstalling) to force an update for VS 2017 Enterprise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Update:***  I ended up reinstalling Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.  It appears to be okay but I will have to wait for a new update before finding out.